# What part is this on my Honda Accord 1996?

Tags: honda, accord, part-identification

I was looking under the hood, trying to learn what's what, and I was wondering what this was.

The circled part.

[image]

Comment: Yor alternator is suspiciously clean. Is it new, or do you just like it better than the other components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Distributor, it's what provides the electrical energy to the spark plugs at the correct time.

Answer (score 2):

Distributor cap, DO NOT switch the cables around